# Visual Studio 2022 MAC Quickview Intellisense stop working

Tags: macos, tooltip, intellisense

I have a strange problem on my Mac(MacBook Pro M1). I'm currently working on a monogame game. Suddenly the Mouseover not Working correctly. As seen on the image below the tooltip just showing an  [O].

Mouseover not working correctly

[image: 1]

Also the Intellisense stoped working correctly. The Tooltip is empty and not showing the Methods Head and other informations.

Intellisense acting strange

[image: 2]

This problem occurs on every New and existing Project. Seems to be a global Visual Studio Problem on my Mac.

**What I have tried is:**

Reboot the Machine, restart the IDE.
Delete the hidden .vs Folder. of the Project
I got the same behavior on a Visual Studio 2019 Mac installation.

I tried other Project Templates and the Tooltips don't show neither.

I uninstalled my installation with the provided uninstall scripts and reinstalled a clean version of Visual Studio but I had no success.

Also I don't have installed any 3rd party software like resharper.

Answer (score 5):

Further to my previous answer, I have confirmed the issue is with MacOS Ventura (beta). I installed MacOS Monterey in a Parallels VM and installed Visual Studio 2022 for Mac and Intellisense tools now working fully and correctly (assuming OP has Ventura installed).

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same issue same issue. I have tried this on Visual Studio Mac 2022 (17.0.7 build 7) and the latest preview ( 17.3 preview build 2089)

[image: Intellisense not displaying]

I loaded the same project using Visual Studio Code and the Intellisense/Tips work just fine:

[image: Visual Studio Code working Example]

I have googled but not seen many other users with the same problem. Not sure if it is due to having MacOS Ventura (beta) installed.

Are you using Ventura? I may have to revert to Monterey to see if this resolves the issues. Even the preview version of VS 2022 doesn't recognise the correct installation path for .NET 6 and had to be manually installed from the cache folder in the VS Installer Cache directory as the GUI fails for this.

Comment: Exact same problem here. I have Ventura beta and IntelliSense is busted.

Comment: @ASTIN77 Did you ever sort this out? I'm new to Macs and didn't know I shouldn't install the update, now I get this issue. I have no backup of Monterey...

Comment: @Veggie I had previously reverted back to Monterey which sorted the issue. I have now installed the official Ventura release (not the Beta) and also installed VS 2022 for Mac (latest Beta/Preview version) and the issue is no longer there. I suggest you update both and see if that resolves for you.

Comment: I was on VS 2019, after upgrading to VS 2022 the issue disappeared. Unfortunately it looks like Microsoft will not be patching 2019 so anyone else with this issue will be stuck upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

The problem still exists, at least with VS 2019 + Ventura 13.0
br wolf
ps: wanted to write this as comment, but i am to new as a Stackoverlow User.