# Visual Studion on Mac dont show errors

Tags: macos, visual-studio

VS 2019 on Mac underlines the error in red, but if you hover over it, it does not decipher what the error is.
[image: Macos Visual Studio 2019 interface]

I tried to google the settings that are responsible for this underlining, but apparently I formulated the queries poorly.
I want it to work on Mac like it does on Windows:[image: Windows Visual Studio 2021 interface]

Comment: I would expect this not to be controlled by a setting but caused by a bug. Did you try restarting VS? Rebooting? Reinstalling?

Comment: I've fixed it by installing Visual Studio 2022. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73150935/visual-studio-2022-mac-quickview-intellisense-stop-working